# Почему не компилируется? С++ Windows Forms

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Уже измотался, я ваще не понимаю в чем ошибка? ХЕЛП! Visual C++ Windows Forms

Файл app.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
using namespace app;
[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}

int main1(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    class TLine 
    {
        public: double x1, x2, y1, y2;
        TLine ( double xx1, double xx2, double yy1, double yy2) 
        {
            x1=xx1;
            x2=xx2;
            y1=yy1;
            y2=yy2;
        }
        double Length()
        {
          double katet1=abs(x2-x1);
          double katet2=abs(y2-y1);
          return sqrt(katet1*katet1+katet2*katet2);
        }
    };

    TLine L1(0,0,0,0);
    L1.x1 = a;
    L1.x2 = b;
    L1.y1 = c;
    L1.y2 = d;
    int result = L1.Length();

    return result;
}
```

Файл AllFunctions.h

```
#pragma once
int main1(int a, int b, int c, int d);
```

Файл Form1.h

```
#pragma once
#include "AllFunctions.h"

namespace app {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtx1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txty1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtx2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txty2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуется переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательный метод для поддержки конструктора - не изменяйте
        /// содержимое данного метода при помощи редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->txtx1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->txty1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->txtx2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->txty2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // txtx1
            // 
            this->txtx1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
            this->txtx1->Name = L"txtx1";
            this->txtx1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->txtx1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->txtx1->Text = L"x1";
            // 
            // txty1
            // 
            this->txty1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 39);
            this->txty1->Name = L"txty1";
            this->txty1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->txty1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->txty1->Text = L"y1";
            // 
            // txtx2
            // 
            this->txtx2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(186, 12);
            this->txtx2->Name = L"txtx2";
            this->txtx2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->txtx2->TabIndex = 2;
            this->txtx2->Text = L"x2";
            // 
            // txty2
            // 
            this->txty2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(186, 38);
            this->txty2->Name = L"txty2";
            this->txty2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->txty2->TabIndex = 3;
            this->txty2->Text = L"y2";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(118, 10);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(62, 22);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 4;
            this->button1->Text = L"length";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(130, 42);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(0, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(298, 69);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txty2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtx2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txty1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtx1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 int a = System::Convert::ToDouble(txtx1->Text);
                 int b = System::Convert::ToDouble(txtx2->Text);
                 int c = System::Convert::ToDouble(txty1->Text);
                 int d = System::Convert::ToDouble(txty2->Text);
                int result = main1(a,b,c,d);
                label1->Text = String::Format("{0}", result);

                // int number = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);// берет значнине с тексбока 1
                //int result = mathadd(number); // 
                //label1->Text = String::Format("You rolled: {0} ", result);//выдает значение

             }
};
}
```

Comment: укажите ошибку

Comment: >я ваще не понимаю в чем ошибка?

Ошибка чего: компиляции, во время выполнения, если собирается - что под отладчиком? Как же вы задолбали, чесслово...

Comment: потому-что у вас даже в слове "комп**и**лируется" синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: @eicto Не совсем так. Не синтаксическая, а орфографическая. Но хрен редьки не слащее (хотя и длиннее)

Comment: закампелеруй закампелеруй еще раз